# Trouble uploading an image file to azure blob storage with azcopy with sas token from php shell_script

Tags: azure

I am facing difficult uploading a picture to azure blob storage from within the php shell_exec() function utilizing azcopy copy command that is:
azcopy copy "picture.jpg" "https://StorageAccount.core.blob.windows.net/container/?sas_token"
Soon after I call upload I get the following response
**===== RESPONSE ERROR (ServiceCode=AuthorizationFailure) ===== Description=This request is not authorized to perform this operation. RequestId:1b8097e7-701e-0010-1a41-f6b19e000000 Time:2020-03-09T18:36:49.3987065Z, Details: Code: AuthorizationFailure PUT https://mnadan.blob.core.windows.net/item/658cbb1d9f44a1992d59a9731318bd2e8af85935bead2a92a68d8c76cbb0a99e.icturef.jpg?se=2020-12-30t22%3A20%3A21z&sig=-REDACTED**
What suprises me is that the same azcopy copy command with same sas token run smoothly when called from the azure portal cloud shell environment.

**0.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 1 Pending, 0 Skipped, 1 Total,
Job e78c4e46-bff1-5345-49ef-14331c064840 summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0333
Total Number Of Transfers: 1
Number of Transfers Completed: 1
Number of Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 4709
Final Job Status: Completed**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the complete SAS Token? Just obfuscate the first few characters of `sig` query string parameter.

Comment: ?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2020-03-12T22:20:21Z&st=2020-03-09T14:20:21Z&sip=0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255&spr=https&sig=*****%**ouV8t17P%2B4263bfOkqjXAl7EJA%3D